# What does Create access rights for Attributes do?

Tags: ibm-doors

I was recently looking at access rights for attributes and seeing if certain attribute properties are controlled by M and others by C, but it seems like I have access to all attribute properties with the M access rights. Does anyone know what Create access rights gives for attributes?

Comment: And I guess on a similar note, does anyone know what Create access rights does for views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With DOORS' concept of hierarchy and inheritance and with the general concept that everything may have its own access rights, not every single access right makes sense.
`C` on "something" allows you to create "something else" that is one hierarchy level below the "something". If you have an `Object` in your `Module` and remove `C` on this `Object`'s properties for a group of users these users may not create `Object`s below this `Object` (example: `Object` containing the heading of chapter 2.3. The users will not be allowed to add any `Object`s in Chapter 2.3).

There is nothing in the DOORS hierarchy below `Attribute definition`s and `Attribute value`s, so setting or removing `C` here has no effect.

In the hierarchy, `Attribute definition`s are directly below the `Module`. So, in order to prevent that a user creates Attributes on their own, you will have to remove `C` for this user on the `Module`, i.e. in the module properties. Unfortunately, this will also disallow that user to create any `Object` on Level 1, leaving them to being next to unable to edit the module content.

Also, removing `C` on the module properties will disallow the users to create `View`s, as `View` definitions are also placed directly below the `Module` in the hierarchy.

Comment: Didn't realize creation of views required C permissions on the Module, but that makes sense if Views are placed below Modules in the hierarchy. Anyways, from what I understand after reading your comment, adding C to the access rights of either Attribute Definitions or Views has no effect whatsoever? IBM could have taken the C access type out like they did with Group permissions, but they chose to leave it.

Comment: Well, they could have removed it, I think. 
The difference is (as far as I can imagine) that users and groups are completely outside the hierarchy, the inheritance mechanism (root folder -> sub folder/projects -> module -> views/attributes/.../objects -> deeper objects) does not work here, so for everything in the hierarchy they use one mechanism and groups security have a different implementation. `C` is usually inherited for AccessDef and they did not want to break the inheritance chain, I guess. 
At least they removed the "propagate" part of the dialog, which really would not make sense.